# Why am I getting this error in react - An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I'm a new JavaScript developer and I'm building a banking application in React. When I create a new user, I can't deposit and withdraw money, or update my transactions list on my All Data page. I get the error...

"An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

When I delete the newTransactions variable and user.transactions.push in my deposit function in actions.js, the code works fine but it doesn't push the transactions to my All Data page. And when logging in with a preset user, everything works as expected.

actions.js

```
import { findIndex } from "lodash";

export const useActions = (state, dispatch) =\> {
// Creates a new user
const addUser = (newUser) =\> {
const newUsers = \[...state.users\];
newUsers.push(newUser);
dispatch({
type: "ADD_USER",
payload: newUsers,
});
};

// Attempts to login with provided credentials
const logIn = (credentials) =\> {
const currentUser = state.users.find(
(element) =\>
element.password === credentials.password &&
element.email === credentials.email
);
if (currentUser) {
dispatch({
type: "LOGIN",
payload: { ...currentUser },
});
} else {
alert("Invalid username and/or password");
}
};

const withdraw = (amount) =\> {
const userIndex = findIndex(
state.users,
(element) =\> element.email === state.currentUser.email
);
const newUsers = \[...state.users\];
const user = newUsers\[userIndex\];
const newTransaction = {
type: "WITHDRAW",
amount: amount,
date: new Date(),
};
user.transactions.push(newTransaction);
user.balance -= amount;
dispatch({
type: "UPDATE_USERS",
payload: newUsers,
});

      dispatch({
         type: "UPDATE_USER",
         payload: {
            ...state.currentUser,
            balance: state.currentUser.balance - amount,
         },
      });

};

const deposit = (amount) =\> {
const userIndex = findIndex(
state.users,
(element) =\> element.email === state.currentUser.email
);
const newUsers = \[...state.users\];
const user = newUsers\[userIndex\];
const newTransaction = {
type: "DEPOSIT",
amount: amount,
date: new Date(),
};
user.transactions.push(newTransaction);
user.balance += amount;
dispatch({
type: "UPDATE_USERS",
payload: newUsers,
});

      dispatch({
         type: "UPDATE_USER",
         payload: {
            ...state.currentUser,
            balance: state.currentUser.balance + amount,
         },
      });

};

const setSuccess = (value) =\> {
dispatch({
type: "SET_SUCCESS",
payload: value,
});
};

const setError = (value) =\> {
dispatch({
type: "SET_ERROR",
payload: value,
});
};

return {
addUser,
logIn,
withdraw,
deposit,
setSuccess,
setError,
};
};
```

alldata.js

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Store } from "../AppState/Store";
import Card from "../util/card";

export default function AllData() {
   const { state } = useContext(Store);

   return (
      <>
         <br />
         <hr className="solid"></hr>
         <h3>ALL DATA</h3>
         <Card
            header="List of all user credentials and balances"
            bgcolor="secondary"
            body={
               <table className="table">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>Transactions</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     {state.users.map((element) => {
                        return (
                           <tr style={{ color: "white" }}>
                              <td>{element.email}</td>
                              <td>{element.name}</td>
                              <td>{element.password}</td>
                              <td>{element.balance}</td>
                              <td>
                                 {element.transactions &&
                                    element.transactions.map(
                                       (transaction, index) => (
                                          <div key={index}>
                                             {transaction.type}: $
                                             {transaction.amount.toFixed()} (
                                             {new Date(
                                                transaction.date
                                             ).toLocaleDateString()}
                                             )
                                          </div>
                                       )
                                    )}
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        );
                     })}
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            }
         />
         <br />
      </>
   );
}
```

deposit.js

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Store } from "../AppState/Store";
import Card from "../util/card";
import Error from "../util/error";
export default function Deposit() {
  const { state, actions } = useContext(Store);

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      amount: 0,
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      const amount = parseFloat(values.amount);
      actions.deposit(amount);
      actions.setSuccess(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        actions.setSuccess(false);
      }, 3000);
    },
    validate: (values) => {
      const errors = {};
      if (!values.amount || values.amount === "")
        errors.amount = "Field Required";
      if (values.amount !== "" && isNaN(parseFloat(values.amount)))
        errors.amount = "Numerical Values Only";
      if (values.amount < 0) errors.amount = "Positive Numbers Only";
      return errors;
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <br />
      <hr className="solid"></hr>
      <h3>DEPOSIT</h3>
      <Card
        bgcolor="secondary"
        body={
          <>
            {state.currentUser && (
              <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} id="deposit-form">
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div
                      className="col"
                      style={{ fontSize: "100px", marginTop: "-40px" }}
                    >
                      Balance:{" "}
                    </div>
                    <div
                      className="col"
                      id="user-balance"
                      style={{ fontSize: "100px", marginTop: "-40px" }}
                    >
                      {state.currentUser.balance}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="amount-container">
                    <div className="row">
                      <h4>Deposit Amount</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="fields">
                      <input
                        style={{ width: "300px" }}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="amountField"
                        name="amount"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        value={formik.values.amount}
                        aria-label="deposit-field"
                      />
                      <br />
                      {formik.errors.amount ? (
                        <Error id="emailError" message={formik.errors.amount} />
                      ) : null}
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        id="submitBtn"
                        disabled={!(formik.isValid && formik.dirty)}
                      >
                        Deposit
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            )}
            {!state.currentUser && <div>Must Be Logged-In</div>}
          </>
        }
      />
      <br />
      {state.success && (
        <div
          className={"alert alert-success mx-auto w-25 p-2"}
          role="alert"
          style={{ height: "110px" }}
        >
          <p className="fs-1 text-center">Success!</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <br />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: where is `submitForm()` defined here? anyways whatever array you are trying to push into is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added

```
  if (!user.transactions) {
     user.transactions = []; // Create an empty array if it doesn't exist
  }
```

into my deposit function.